# Client Object Model don't work without "cookies"

Tags: development

Problem could be reproduced for all types of Client Model Object (Managed, JS, etc..)

for example (Managed Client Model Object):

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("http:\\WebApplicationURL"))
{
    var site = context.Web;
    context.Load(site, s => s.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(site.Title);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

1) All works fine if 
cookies is turned on in web.config for Web Application 
 ()

in "fiddler":

> Request: POST /_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery HTTP/1.1
>
> Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

2) If using cookieless session ()

> "context.ExecuteQuery()" generate WebException "The remote server
>   returned an error: (404) Not Found."

in "fiddler":

> Request: GET
>   /(S(1j0bsz55e3dk1455dhagx4ry))/_vti_bin/client.svc/ntlm/ProcessQuery
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> Response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

What settings should be applied for correct working "Client Model Object" in cookieless  session or "Client Model Object" couldn't be used without cookies at all?

**EDIT**

Some additional problems description:

1. with cookies
   context.ExecuteQuery() transform in 4 requests (all requests/response aren't contains cookies) (

   - 3 calls to /_vti_bin/sites.asmx requesting the FormsDigest information, which contains the security token.
   - 1 to /_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery

   **Request:**
       POST WebApplication/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery HTTP/1.1
       X-RequestDigest: 0xECF432C8EB314A8C6B5ED6AB71466996B36E554AC51D445633AA8D038FCD9CB410A6965E6D0F33D6AF70F273D05510F55C1AD37089648F1EE5317A3B0F194EFE,30 Jan 2014 13:50:00 -0000
       Content-Type: text/xml
       X-RequestForceAuthentication: true
       Host: WebApplication
       Content-Length: 612
       Expect: 100-continue

   **Response:**
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Cache-Control: private
   Content-Type: application/json
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
   SPRequestGuid: ea3f7a0b-2170-413a-8e42-9d2b1e56fcde
   X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.7015
   X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
   Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2014 13:50:00 GMT
   Content-Length: 273

   [
   {
   "SchemaVersion":"14.0.0.0","LibraryVersion":"14.0.7010.1000","ErrorInfo":null
   },2,{
   "IsNull":false
   },4,{
   "IsNull":false
   },5,{
   "*ObjectType*":"SP.Web","*ObjectIdentity*":"740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:web:622c751b-aedf-4185-9737-f0768a64142d","Title":"sc1718"
   }
   ]
2. without cookies:
   context.ExecuteQuery() transform in 5 requests (all requests/response aren't contains cookies)

   - 3 calls the same as "with cookies"
   - 2 calls to _vti_bin/client.svc/ntlm/ProcessQuery

   1)
   **Request:**
   POST WebApplication/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery HTTP/1.1
   X-RequestDigest: 0xF71F2826979622452C5DDE5F3A1D55BC3B7EAD70E0798452D1F47A74242CC92A76F5DC84209CECE798F2F93735CCC41527714C2DE58113194962843BB065BF98,30 Jan 2014 09:44:22 -0000
   Content-Type: text/xml
   X-RequestForceAuthentication: true
   Host: WebApplication
   Content-Length: 612
   Expect: 100-continue

   **Response:**
   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Location: /(S(zvjwtkawdkuozwfurptxk245))/_vti_bin/client.svc/ntlm/ProcessQuery
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
   SPRequestGuid: 1229be02-6a64-4f31-bb21-fc91f1d10bd8
   X-SharePointHealthScore: 1
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.7015
   X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
   Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2014 09:44:21 GMT
   Content-Length: 195

   Object moved

   ### Object moved to here.

2)
**Request:**
GET 
WebApplication/(S(zvjwtkawdkuozwfurptxk245))/_vti_bin/client.svc/ntlm/ProcessQuery HTTP/1.1
X-RequestDigest: 0xF71F2826979622452C5DDE5F3A1D55BC3B7EAD70E0798452D1F47A74242CC92A76F5DC84209CECE798F2F93735CCC41527714C2DE58113194962843BB065BF98,30 Jan 2014 09:44:22 -0000
Content-Type: text/xml
X-RequestForceAuthentication: true
Host: share1:1718

**Response:**
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: c1e7007a-d866-446d-add5-ea4dee2cba0e
X-SharePointHealthScore: 1
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.7015
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2014 09:44:21 GMT
Content-Length: 1019

#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}
Service

Service

Endpoint not found.

Answer (score 1):

you need cookies as its used for form autentication:

> The FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo class is used by the
>   ClientContext.FormsAuthenticationLogin method by first calling the
>   EnsureLogin method to check for authentication cookies.

more detailed info can be found here: goto Authentication section!

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268193/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-Part-1

taken from link above from fiddler you can see where its setting the cookie authentication in bold

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Cache-Control: private
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>
> SPRequestGuid: 22e3f795-a5c9-492d-a551-3e950b8f1c10
>
> **Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={4e4cffb3-203e-4857-8f5a-90a4b18789a4};
>   path=/**
>
> X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>
> X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
>
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6029
>
> Content-Length: 460

**EDIT**

Ok so now i know your using windows authentication you need to send the credentails using the following:

```
clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;

FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo formsAuthInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("MyUser", "MyPassword");

clientContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = formsAuthInfo;
```

in your case:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("http:\\WebApplicationURL"))
{
    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
    FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo formsAuthInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("MyUserName", "MyUserPassword");
    context.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = formsAuthInfo;
    var site = context.Web;
    context.Load(site, s => s.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(site.Title);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

or anonymous user:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("http:\\WebApplicationURL"))
{
    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Anonymous;
    var site = context.Web;
    context.Load(site, s => s.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(site.Title);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535729(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT 2**

lol your not making it easy!

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("http:\\WebApplicationURL"))
{
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "Userpassword", "domain");
    var site = context.Web;
    context.Load(site, s => s.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(site.Title);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I use windows authentication.

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: Unfortunately "Forms Authentication" is disabled for the site on IIS

Comment: have you tried the anonymous user method?>

Comment: Yes: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: I have add some information from Fiddler (see my question "Edit")

Comment: just ammended my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think authentication is wrong way for investigation, because all requests for getting the FormsDigest information (which contains the security token) are identical with or without cookies. Problems with rediraction:

```
 -> POST WebApplication/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery 
 <- HTTP/1.1 302 Found Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Location: /(S(zvjwtkawdkuozwfurptxk245))/_vti_bin/client.svc/ntlm/ProcessQuery
```

and second request on the url is failed:

```
 -> GET WebApplication/(S(zvjwtkawdkuozwfurptxk245))/_vti_bin/client.svc/ntlm/ProcessQuery
 <- HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```